# oXYgen Editor content causing issues while publishing in Tridion Docs

Tags: tridion-docs

In our Tridion Docs implementation, we often have topics that have images. Now most editors while inserting images also add the `<alt>` element, and include elements like `<i>` within it as shown below:
[image]

This is causing issues in publishing such content from the Tridion Docs CMS.
We have looked for patterns that can be added to the *OXYGEN_INSTALL_DIR/frameworks/dita/resources/dita-1.2-for-xslt2-mandatory.sch* file, but there is nothing for the image alt element.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated as this is quite a recurring problem, and would be nice to have a rule set to prevent content editors from using these elements withing the  element.

Comment: The below pattern works for all types of elements within the **<alt>**:
'...
<rule context="alt/*">
            <report test="true()" role="error" sqf:fix="removeMarkup"> alt should not contain
                additional elements, only text. </report>
            <sqf:fix id="removeMarkup">
                <sqf:description>
                    <sqf:title>alt should not contain additional elements. Remove markup keeping the text content.</sqf:title>
                </sqf:description>
                <sqf:replace match="." select="node()"/>
            </sqf:fix>
        </rule>
...'

Comment: Did you intend to put this as an answer?

Comment: yes, this was the answer o my issue.